# how to silence warnings about ignored files in eslint

Tags: eslint

After setting up `eslint` and adding some files in the ignore list, every time that eslint is run it produces warnings about files that are ignored:

```
 /path/to/file/name.min.js
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to override
```

How can this warning be silenced?

Comment: I've done some work in the past few months on how ESLint ignore warnings work.  Are you still having troubles with recent versions of ESLint?

Comment: As of end of 2023, we have the `--no-warn-ignored` CLI flag available, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77758970/9655481).

Answer (score 43):

One workaround I know at the moment is `--quiet` option, which suppresses all warnings. Of course that doesn't make sense if you have "warn" rules in your config.

Another way not to show that warning is to use dir names: `eslint src` instead of globbing patterns: `eslint src/*`.

Comment: Using directory names instead of globbing all files did the trick!

Comment: `eslint src` worked... But, i am curious how it is different than `eslint src/**`?

Comment: @mukesh210, the differene is that in the first example you are telling the eslint to lint the `src` directory so it lints it while skiping the ignored files. However if you call `eslint src/**` you are saying "lint every single file that matches this pattern". And since the ignored files match the pattern `src/**` you are literally telling the eslint to lint those ignored file so eslint warns you it cannot perform your request.

Answer (score 43):

Check if you're running eslint with an **unquoted glob argument**.
If so, **put the glob in quotes**.

`eslint src/**` ❌ Bad (no quotes = OS will expand into many args)

`eslint "src/**"` ✔️ Good (quotes = a single string argument)

#### Why?

If you call eslint using a cli glob pattern not in quotes, e.g. `eslint src/**`, that glob gets **expanded** into all matching files ***and passed to eslint as a gigantic list of cli arguments***. e.g. `eslint path/to/file/name.min.js src/foo.js src/bar.js src/manymore.js .....`

So when eslint ignores a file due to your ignore pattern, yet that file was explicitly passed as a command line argument, eslint is warning us

> *eslint speaking:*
> "Um, I ignored /path/to/file/name.min.js because of an ignore pattern, but you explicitly passed it to me to lint, so this must not be what you wanted, right?"

But when you pass the glob in **quotes**, e.g. `eslint "src/**"`, the glob is not expanded to many arguments; rather, it's just a single string argument, and eslint is the one who knows it's a glob but since it takes care of figuring out which files to match it can do so while respecting eslintignore. So there's nothing weird going on that eslint thinks it should warn you about.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

### The solution for `Lint Staged` & `Husky` errors

```js
// lint-staged.config.js
const { ESLint } = require("eslint");

const removeIgnoredFiles = async (files) => {
  const eslint = new ESLint();
  const ignoredFiles = await Promise.all(files.map((file) => eslint.isPathIgnored(file)));
  const filteredFiles = files.filter((_, i) => !ignoredFiles[i]);
  return filteredFiles.join(" ");
};

module.exports = {
  "*.{js,ts}": async (files) => {
    const filesToLint = await removeIgnoredFiles(files);
    return [`eslint --max-warnings=0 ${filesToLint}`];
  },
};
```

If the file is ignored by ESLint (i.e. in `.eslintignore`), this snippet filters the file and does not pass it through the ESLint CLI.

ref: [Testing Library - Aug 2022](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/25f73c546c586adf27fbc50b169d5d42afcc2f95/lint-staged.config.js)

Comment: `isPathIgnored` returns a Promise. How does this work for you?

Comment: @jeron-diovis I've updated my snippet to the latest API. Please consider upvoting if this worked for you.

Comment: Great piece of code, can't believe it haven't got any upvote till now!

Answer (score 21):

You can't and they don't plan on fixing it since they don't consider it a bug.  So if you pass in a file that's being ignored them it will tell you it didn't process linting rules because it's ignored: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5623

We run pre-commit hooks to lint code before committing, so ended up needing to write some additional code to differentiate between actual Warnings and File ignored warnings and only fail linting if an actual warning or error is thrown.

Comment: I read the issue at the link you provided and there is the explenation why it is really not a bug. One should not use a star in the path when calling eslint.

Comment: I think this is the root issue.  I got here due to the same use-case, and this use-case isn't considered atm by the eslint devs.  So yeah it's not a bug but I believe it's a valid feature request.

Answer (score 6):

I found the REAL answer here:

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5623

The problem in my case was in the way I called eslint. I used `eslint src/*` but it should be `eslint src/`. (Or in your case it might be `eslint .` instead of `eslint *`)

The reason why you get the warning is that by using the star, you are telling the eslint that you want to lint EVERY single file which does not make sense if you ignore some files. So by omiting the star you are making the eslint to decide what to lint and it will skip the ignored files without any warning.

Answer (score 2):

Eslint throws this warning on telling it to lint a file, at the same time as having the file ignored. `src/*` is actually passing every file single file uniquely, while only passing `src` would let eslint ignore the files without warnings

If you are using `lint-staged`, it will pass every single staged file that matches the lint-staged regex. If matching, and you put it inside ignore, eslint gets confused and outputs a warning

```
 "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx,js}": [ // <-- this regex needs to be changed to not match your files
      "eslint --fix --max-warnings 0 --ignore-path '.eslintignore' --plugin tsc --rule 'tsc/config: [2, {configFile: \"./tsconfig.json\"}]'",
      "prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --write"
    ],
    "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix",
    "*.{js,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  },
```

For me, I just wanted to exclude some js files, so I just removed the js matching inside `"*.{ts,tsx,js}"`

Answer (score 0):

try with `--ext`. In my case, I replaced matching from:

```
eslint modules/**/*{js,vue}
```

to:

```
eslint --ext .js,.vue .
```

Warnings with *File ignored because...* are gone, but others warnings remain.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for Next.js `next lint` and a `.lintstagedrc.js` file. This removes the files that have that warning from the final string of files to lint.

```
// .lintstagedrc.js

const path = require("path");

const ignorePaths = ["types/global.d.ts", ".lintstagedrc.js"];

const buildEslintCommand = (filenames) => {
  return `next lint --fix --max-warnings=0 --file ${filenames
    .reduce((files, file) => {
      const pathToFile = path.relative(process.cwd(), file);
      if (!ignorePaths.includes(pathToFile)) files.push(pathToFile);
      return files;
    }, [])
    .join(" --file ")}`;
};

module.exports = {
  "*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}": [buildEslintCommand],
  "*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,css,scss,md}": "prettier --write",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

##### **`--no-warn-ignored` CLI flag for ESLint Flat config mode.**

As of August 1, 2023 (merge date of pull request), we now have a proper solution for this problem. It was discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15010) and then solved in [this pull request](https://github.com/eslint/rfcs/pull/90). Thanks a lot to [Domantas Petrauskas](https://github.com/domnantas) and the ESLint team for having shipped this.

If you're using the new Flat ESLint config, you have the following CLI flag available

```
--no-warn-ignored               Suppress warnings when the file list includes ignored files. *Flat Config Mode Only*
```

See the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#options) (section "Miscellaneous").
Note that the devs decided to move forward and only have this available in the newer Flat ESLint config easing the implementation, see [this](https://github.com/eslint/rfcs/pull/90#issuecomment-1386024387) and [this](https://github.com/eslint/rfcs/pull/90#issuecomment-1464891552) comment.