# Disable ESLint warnings on a file?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have just started to use linters, and am currently using the [`linter-eslint`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint) package to integrate javascript linting into atom (my IDE of choice.)

Now ESLint is giving me this warning for a `.atom-build.js` file I have inside my current project directory:

```
File ignored by default. Use a negated ignore pattern to override.
```

I want to suppress this warning, because it is bugging me that everything else is fine but there is still this red X in the bottom-left corner of atom.

I tried adding the line:

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

to the top of my file, but it doesn't remove the warning.

[image: /* eslint-disable */ > File ignored by default. Use a negated ignore pattern to override.]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/HGyBx3.png))</sub>

Comment: Like duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927772/how-to-silence-warnings-about-ignored-files-in-eslint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just add the following line to your `.eslintignore` file, essentially negating the default ignoring of the file.

```
!.atom-build.js
```

Since the file is ignored by default, I don't believe a comment in the header with change anything.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish a similar thing using the `.eslintrc.json` file? Because I already have one of those...

Comment: @minseong I don't think so, it's not listed here: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: Whoops, this did work! I had to first save my unchanged file for the linting to update...