# "No files matching the pattern "src" were found." when using "npx eslint src" or "npx eslint src/"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, ubuntu-20.04

I've just set up a create-react-app project with typescript. I've added eslint with `npx eslint --init`. When I run `npx eslint src/` or `npx eslint src` I get an error:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.18.0

No files matching the pattern "src" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

However, if I use this command: `npx eslint src/*` then it works. This is fine, but some guides and stackoverflow comments ([eg on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927772/how-to-silence-warnings-about-ignored-files-in-eslint)) I've seen show that the commands that don't work for me are working for seemingly everyone else. What am I doing wrong?

`eslint.js`

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: ["plugin:react/recommended", "standard"],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  rules: {
    semi: "off",
    quotes: "off",
    "space-before-function-paren": "off",
  },
  ignorePatterns: ["**/*.css", "**/*.svg"],
};
```

`package.json`:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
    "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1"
  },
```

Comment: Works for me. I use `npx eslint src/* --fix`

Comment: What platform are you running as your OS?  Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, MacOS???

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. I've just edited my question to show in the tags. Thanks!

Also, That command also works for me. I was just wondering why removing the asterisk works for other users but not for me.

Comment: Oh, I get what your asking... The reason I asked about OS is because on windows, when you use the astriks you have to wrap with quotes. As far as using only src goes, the question you posted the link to, the people who wrote answers, and commented on the answers, shouldn't have authored those answers & comments using the `npx eslint src/` command. Its an incorrect reference. When the ESLint command is used it works off of your POSIX file system, where Node.js works off your possix system, it first evaluates the path, and if the path does not start with the systems root path -> `/`

Comment: which is the Root pathname for every POSIX file system (or atleast everyone that I have worked on) it seems silly that `/` wouldn't be a standard, anyways, when node sees that the path does not match the POSIX root-path, it infers that the path is relative to the CWD (or Current Working Directory) (also refered to as the acronym, and BASH command, `pwd`)

Comment: ESLint seems to not seem to be able to infer that you are calling it from the CWD, and instead it needs to be exlicitly added, henceforth, the working command, which is `npx eslint ./src`

Comment: The important thing to note, is that two different programs (or two different pieces of software) are used when referencing a path in an ESLint CLI argument. I believe that a NPM module is responsible for the GLOB path (src/*), and eslint has (obviously) built-in code for handling the "./src" path

Comment: In truth, it may seem like some details are missing, and thats because I didn't build the software, but there should be enough information included in the above comments to help you gain a better understanding of what happens when you pass the two different types of arguments to ESLint.

Comment: Wow dude, that's a great response. Thanks for the comprehensive explanation!

Comment: Yea but its not correct. Not totally anyways. Its an accurate depiction of how legacy ESLint use to work. The reason I am so thorough in my response is because this question has lead me to researching this entire subject for 2 days now. Anyways, I laid out how to get the command working below.

Comment: Initially, it didn't work for me either, it seems that its important to have everything updated, and the latest version of everything.

Comment: I also work in construction & write code, but I am a carpenter not an engineer. I started going back to school 5 years ago for computer science.

Comment: I still build houses during the day, and write code by night.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the comments I left were incorrect. This question left me reading about ESLint, how it works, and how the `npm`/`npx` commands differ.

#### So here is the deal

###### NOTE: *"I use the syntax `$(pwd)` to refer to the current-working-directory, because it's not a pseudo representation of a path, but rather a command, wrapped as such, that it can be interpreted, and ran, by the *BASH* shell."*

In the comments, I wrote about eslint resolving paths, and its inability to infer the meaning of the **CLI** passed argument `src`, ***as shown in this snippet:***

```
  /* COMMAND-1 */

  $ eslint src
```

Thinking back on it, that was a really dumb comment to make, that I shouldn't have said. The reason it wasn't smart, is because, the way the path is resolved completely changes when you use the following:

```
  /* COMMAND-2 */

  $ npx eslint src
```

Looking at the two commands together, side by side, is helpful in the sense that it allows us to draw a side by side comparison, however, there really isn't much to compare, because of how different these two commands are.

So the first command, `COMMAND-1`, resolves src as if it were a path, however, `COMMAND-2` executes an ESLint internal command, hence the **"X"** in `npx`, which is the same as executing...

###### `npm exec` or `npm x`

In other words, the following; `npx eslint src` can also be executed using `npm x eslint src`, or `npm exec eslint src`.

So, as stated above, **the argument `src` is not a system `file-path`, but rather, it's an internal ESLint command that offers a cute little CLI printout of your errors. **ITS ACTUALLY PRETTY COOL**

#### Initially the Command didn't work for me either

The problem I had, looks, like it was the same problem your having.

###### **The solution is quite simple.**

1. Update NPM to the latest version.
2. Update NPX to the latest version. (more on this below)
3. Update Node.js to the latest version
4. Update ESLint to the latest version
5. Update all of your proj's pkgs, then audit them with the fix command (more on this below).

So NPM comes with the NPX command embedded in it, and technically, `npx` is the `npm` command, just ran as `npm x` or `npm exec`, however; from the standpoint of your file-system, (in other words, looking at the commands from the context of `/usr/bin/...`) they are two different commands.

So I know alot about ubuntu because it was my OS for 7 years. About a year ago I switched to `Fedora 36: Workstation` and was glad I did. I made the change because of the issues associated with installing Node.js & NPM. Ubuntu makes it difficult. The reason I use Linux in the first place is because software runs in an environment that suited for running software, and not suited for protecting the proprietary licenses associated with the software. Anyways, long story made short... the best way for you to upgrade NPX (which means upgrading NPM, which means you need to upgrade Node.js), is to install the latest version of Node.js, go into the directory, and create symbolic links for `npm`, `node`, `npx`, in your `/usr/bin` directory and then upgrade eslint (globally) to version `v8.18.0`. You may also need to create a symbolic link for ESLint.

---

On a final note, just to point out somthing. You notice your ESLint version your `package.json` file is `v8.18.0`? and the version in the error you are getting is `v8.1.0`?

That is because your local & global eslint installs are different versions of eslint. You should try to always keep everything the same version.

Right now your system is trying to execute `npx eslint src` as if `src` is a path, but one everything is updated, you should have the software needed, for eslint & npm to know that its an ESLint command your trying to execute, not a path.

Comment: Wow man, thanks so much. Are you going to get a job in tech? Sounds like it's high time for you!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have this property in tsconfig.ts file :

```
"baseUrl": "."
```